# How can I replace Fragment inside Dialog inside a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-library

I'm trying to use https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon library in order to produce an EmojiKeyboard over the softkeyboard just like WhatsApp and Telegram does.

After some research, I figure that the way they do is by creating a Dialog over the soft keyboard. The library is a fragment that needs to replace some element of the layout in execution time. The replacement happens int this class:

```
/**
 * Class responsible for managin user's interaction with the Emoji Keyboard
 */
public class EmojiKeyboardManager {

    public static final String TAG = "EmojiKeyboardManager";

    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;

    private FrameLayout mEmojiconContainer;
    private EmojiconEditText mEditEmojicon;
    private LinearLayout mEmojiconButton;
    private ImageView mEmojiconButtonImg;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public EmojiKeyboardManager(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.implementEmojiconButton();
        this.implementInputTextListener();
        //this.initEmojiconFragment(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    // INITIALIZATIONS
    private void implementEmojiconButton() {
        this.mEmojiconButtonImg = (ImageView) this.mActivity.findViewById(R.id.emojiButton);
        this.mEmojiconButton = (LinearLayout) this.mActivity.findViewById(R.id.emojiButtonWrapper);
        EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEmojiconButtonImg.setSelected(Boolean.FALSE);
        this.mEmojiconButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEmojiconButtonImg.isSelected()) {
                    EmojiKeyboardManager.this.hideEmojiconKeyboard(Boolean.TRUE);
                } else {
                    EmojiKeyboardManager.this.showEmojiconKeyboard();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showEmojiconKeyboard() {
        LayoutUtil.dismissSoftKeyboard(this.mEditEmojicon);
        EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEmojiconButtonImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_black_36dp);

        DialogFragment newFragment = SampleDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.show(this.mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

        //this.mEmojiconContainer.setVisibility(FrameLayout.VISIBLE);
        EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEmojiconButtonImg.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public void hideEmojiconKeyboard(Boolean showSoftkeyboard) {
        EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEmojiconButtonImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.input_emoji);
        LayoutUtil.dismissSoftKeyboard(EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEditEmojicon);
        //this.mEmojiconContainer.setVisibility(FrameLayout.GONE);
        EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEmojiconButtonImg.setSelected(Boolean.FALSE);
        if (showSoftkeyboard) {
            EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEditEmojicon.requestFocus();
            LayoutUtil.showSoftKeyboard(EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEditEmojicon);
        }
    }

    private void implementInputTextListener() {
        this.mEditEmojicon = (EmojiconEditText) this.mActivity.findViewById(R.id.message);
        this.mEditEmojicon.clearFocus();
    }

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public EmojiconEditText getmEditEmojicon() {
        return this.mEditEmojicon;
    }

    public Boolean isEmojikeyboardAttached() {
        return EmojiKeyboardManager.this.mEmojiconButtonImg.isSelected();
    }

}
```

In order to achieve what I need I'm using a subclass of DialogFragment that creates a Dialog like that:

```
public class SampleDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private Dialog dialog;

    static SampleDialogFragment newInstance() {
        SampleDialogFragment f = new SampleDialogFragment();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.dialog = new Dialog(this.getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);

        this.dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rsc_emoji_keyboard);
        this.dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        this.dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
        this.dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
        this.dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = this.dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = (int) App.context().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.soft_keyboard_min_height);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
        lp.dimAmount = 0;

        return this.dialog;
    }
}
```

And I display the Dialog like that:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = SampleDialogFragment.newInstance();
.show(this.mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

The layout of the Dialog looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/emoji_keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/soft_keyboard_min_height"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where the FrameLayout should be replaced by the Library Fragment. I've tried to use the replace Fragment code after creating the Dialog in the Parent Activity and also overriding the show() method of the DialogFragment but I always get a view not found exception. How can I replace the framelayout in by the library fragment?

EDIT:
Follow it is the stack trace

```
02-13 22:47:50.613 25553-25606/br.com.instachat.demo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-13 22:47:50.725 25553-25606/br.com.instachat.demo I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU (I3193f6e94a)
                                                                   OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.28.00.02
                                                                   Build Date: 10/09/15 Fri
                                                                   Local Branch: mybranch15039904
                                                                   Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.3_rb1.2
                                                                   Local Patches: NONE
                                                                   Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
02-13 22:47:50.727 25553-25606/br.com.instachat.demo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-13 22:47:50.757 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-13 22:47:50.791 25553-25623/br.com.instachat.demo I/RegIntentService: br.com.instachat.demo:string/token_received_successfully
02-13 22:47:50.796 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-13 22:47:51.395 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo I/RegIntentService: br.com.instachat.demo:string/token_sent_to_app_server_successfully
02-13 22:47:51.410 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo I/FragmentContacts: br.com.instachat.demo:string/contact_sync_success
02-13 22:47:53.010 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo I/FragmentContacts: br.com.instachat.demo:string/get_chatroomid_success
02-13 22:47:53.011 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo I/FragmentContacts:  chatroom retrieved (via request) has title: Hall 9000
02-13 22:47:53.066 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
02-13 22:47:53.440 25553-25606/br.com.instachat.demo D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb82bf2a0 (LinearLayout) with handle 0xb83b6700
02-13 22:47:53.952 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0d00e3 (br.com.instachat.demo:id/emoji_keyboard) for fragment EmojiconsFragment{d8f31ba #1 id=0x7f0d00e3}
02-13 22:47:53.952 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
02-13 22:47:53.953 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:   Local FragmentActivity a698ff2 State:
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     mLoadersStarted=true
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:   Active Fragments in 6fb086b:
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     #0: SampleDialogFragment{3355fc8 #0 dialog}
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#0 mContainerId=#0 mTag=dialog
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mState=5 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
02-13 22:47:53.957 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{6fb086b in HostCallbacks{d98e861}}
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@d98e861
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     #1: EmojiconsFragment{d8f31ba #1 id=0x7f0d00e3}
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#7f0d00e3 mContainerId=#7f0d00e3 mTag=null
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mState=0 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:1 mBackStackNesting=0
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{6fb086b in HostCallbacks{d98e861}}
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@d98e861
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       mArguments=Bundle[{useSystemDefaults=false}]
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:   Added Fragments:
02-13 22:47:53.958 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     #0: SampleDialogFragment{3355fc8 #0 dialog}
02-13 22:47:53.959 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     #1: EmojiconsFragment{d8f31ba #1 id=0x7f0d00e3}
02-13 22:47:53.959 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:   FragmentManager misc state:
02-13 22:47:53.959 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@d98e861
02-13 22:47:53.959 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@d98e861
02-13 22:47:53.959 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
02-13 22:47:53.959 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:   View Hierarchy:
02-13 22:47:53.959 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:     com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{f889320 V.ED.... ... 0,0-1080,1920}
02-13 22:47:53.959 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       android.widget.LinearLayout{5a1ae9e V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1776}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{ceeaf86 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #10203ab android:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:         android.widget.FrameLayout{3b1ca13 V.E..... ... 0,72-1080,1776}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:           android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout{bf70450 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1704 #7f0d0080 app:id/action_bar_root}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat{2bfc047 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0d0081 app:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{15d6649 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1704 #1020002 android:id/content}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:               android.widget.RelativeLayout{f64fb4e V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1704 #7f0d0094 app:id/activity_canvas}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                 android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout{ee4f46f V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,168 #7f0d0095 app:id/toolbar_wrapper}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{6d0157c V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,168 #7f0d0096 app:id/toolbar}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.RelativeLayout{c997e5a V.E..... ... 168,0-528,168}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                       com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView{d196b08 V.ED.... ... 0,15-135,152 #7f0d0097 app:id/thumbnail}
02-13 22:47:53.962 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.LinearLayout{576688b V.E..... ... 150,27-360,141}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{dc70d68 V.ED.... ... 0,0-210,65 #7f0d0098 app:id/name}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{a469581 V.ED.... ... 0,65-99,114 #7f0d0099 app:id/status}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.ImageButton{70d1e05 VFED..C. ... 0,0-168,168}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView{48ca098 V.E..... ... 816,0-1080,168}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView{e995357 VFED..CL ... 0,12-144,156 #7f0d00f2 app:id/action_attach_media}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton{41af862 VFED..C. ... 144,12-264,156}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{4612626 VFE..... F.. 0,168-1080,1506 #7f0d009a app:id/messages}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                 android.widget.LinearLayout{e610267 V.E..... ... 0,1506-1080,1704 #7f0d009b app:id/bottomLayoutWrapper}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                   android.widget.LinearLayout{b39814 V.E..... ... 24,24-1056,174}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.LinearLayout{84608bd V.E..... ... 0,0-882,150}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.LinearLayout{ba97eb2 V.E...C. ... 1,0-145,150 #7f0d00da app:id/emojiButtonWrapper}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{b715e03 V.ED.... .S. 36,39-108,111 #7f0d00db app:id/emojiButton}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                       com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText{33c2180 VFED..CL ... 145,0-822,150 #7f0d00b7 app:id/message}
02-13 22:47:53.963 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.LinearLayout{bcf73b9 V.E..... ... 822,38-822,111}
02-13 22:47:53.964 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.LinearLayout{624b074 VFE..... ... 0,0-0,0}
02-13 22:47:53.964 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView{6acd3fe VFED..CL ... 0,0-0,73 #7f0d00ec app:id/autotext}
02-13 22:47:53.964 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton{4a1d75f VFED..C. ... 882,0-1032,150 #7f0d00dc app:id/send}
02-13 22:47:53.964 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       android.view.View{e881223 V.ED.... ... 0,1776-1080,1920 #1020030 android:id/navigationBarBackground}
02-13 22:47:53.964 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/FragmentManager:       android.view.View{4ba94d9 V.ED.... ... 0,0-1080,72 #102002f android:id/statusBarBackground}
02-13 22:47:53.964 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-13 22:47:53.968 25553-25553/br.com.instachat.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: br.com.instachat.demo, PID: 25553
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00e3 (br.com.instachat.demo:id/emoji_keyboard) for fragment EmojiconsFragment{d8f31ba #1 id=0x7f0d00e3}
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

SOLVED

---

I was able to manage the issue by using the code below:

```
public class SampleDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    static SampleDialogFragment newInstance() {
        SampleDialogFragment f = new SampleDialogFragment();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rsc_emoji_keyboard, container, false);

        this.getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        this.getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
        this.getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
        this.getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = this.getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = (int) App.context().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.soft_keyboard_min_height);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
        lp.dimAmount = 0;

        getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.emoji_keyboard, EmojiconsFragment.newInstance(false))
                .commit();

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Always post the full stack trace of an exception if you want help diagnosing a problem.

Comment: I've edited the question....

Comment: Now you'll probably want to show the class where this line occurs:     `.replace(R.id.emoji_keyboard, EmojiconsFragment.newInstance(false))` since the error is saying that `emoji_keyboard` could not be found.

Comment: Thank you Doug, I was able to solve the issue. I just had to use the inner Dialog of DialogFragment instead of reating a new one. The transaction then must be done using the getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager(). The second one will give me the outside activity fm, that is why I couldn't find the view.